# Cannot get an http markup of google

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get an html markup of google.com using curl in php. I write the following:

```
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$output= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

The following markup is displayed:

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY>
    <H1>302 Moved</H1>
    The document has moved
    <A HREF="http://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=xwX7UuzqNuuk4ATU0YHACQ">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now I'm changed php code to the following:

```
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.ru/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=xwX7UuzqNuuk4ATU0YHACQ");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$output= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;
```

But it doesn't work. `$output` doesn't contains markup of `google.com`. How to fix this?

Comment: So what *does* `$output` contain?

Comment: @Phil output contains nothing.

Comment: Try just curl-ing http://www.google.ru/ without the additional parameters. They are causing another redirect to fire.  If that doesn't work, try running curl in the command line and see what you get for the same URL.

Comment: @dethtron5000 If execute curl_exec($ch) without returntransfer parameter then it work fine.